# Searching a word in an alphabet soup by reading from right to left

Tags: c, matrix

i'm trying next program: the user writes a word and it must be searched in an alphabet soup (a character matrix) by reading from left to right and from right to left.

I have been able to make the program to search from left to right, but I can't get how to read from right to left.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 5
#define M 7

void show_soup(char soup[N][M]);
int search_word(char soup[N][M], char pal[M+1], int row, int col);
int equal_strings (char pal1[], char pal2[]);
int lenght_string (char pal[]);

void main()
{
    int row, column;
    char pal[M];

    char soup[N][M] =
    {
        'A', 'A', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'A', 'P',
        'B', 'N', 'O', 'T', 'R', 'P', 'Y',
        'P', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'W',
        'A', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'I', 'T', 'A',
        'E', 'T', 'O', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'Y',
    };


    show_soup(soup);

    printf("\nWrite a word up to %d letters: ", M);
    gets(pal);


    for(row=0; row<N; row++)
    {
        for(column=0; column<M; column++)
        {
            if(lenght_string(pal)<=M)
            {
                if(search_word(soup, pal, row, column)==1)
                printf("\nIt's in row %d and in column %d: from left to right", row, column);
            }

        }
    }

    for(row=0; row<N; row++)
    {
        for(column=M-1; column>=0; column--)
        {
            if(lenght_string(pal)<=M)
            {
                if(search_word(soup, pal, row, column)==2)
                printf("\nIt's in row %d and in column %d: from right to left", row, column);
            }

        }

    }

}

//measures the lenght of the string received as a parameter
int lenght_string (char pal[M])
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; pal[i] != '\0'; i++);

    return i;
}

//compares two words that are received as parameters,
// returns 1 if they are equal or 0 if they are not
int equal_strings (char pal1[M], char pal2[M])
{
    int i, enc=1;

    for(i=0; pal1[i]!='\0' && pal2[i]!='\0' && enc; i++)
    {
        if(pal1[i]!=pal2[i])
            enc=0;
    }

    return enc;
}

//shows the soup on the screen
void show_soup(char soup[N][M])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("                        ");

        for(j=0; j<M; j++)
            printf("%2c", soup[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

//Searches the word horizontally from a position received as a parameter
//Returns 0 if not found, 1 if it's found from left to right and 2 from right to left
int search_word(char soup[N][M], char pal[M+1], int row, int col)
{
    int i, j, result=1, result2=2;

    char pal2[M+1], pal3[M+1];

    for(i=0; pal[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        pal2[i]=soup[row][col+i];
        pal3[i]=pal2[lenght_string(pal2)-i-1];
    }

    if(equal_strings(pal, pal2)!=1)
        result=0;

   else if(equal_strings(pal, pal3)!=1)
        result2=0;

    return result;
    return result2;
}
```

I think that the problem comes from matching pal3 with pal2. But I have tried other method like:

```
int i, j;

    char pal2[M+1], pal3[M+1];

    for(i=0, j=lenght_string(pal); pal[i]!='\0' || j>=0; i++, j--)
    {
        pal2[i]=soup[row][col+i];
        pal3[i]=pal2[j];
    }

}
```

But it still doesn't work.

If someone could help me, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: `char pal[M];` --> `char pal[M+1];`

Comment: `j=lenght_string(pal); pal[i]!='\0' || j>=0;` --> `j=lenght_string(pal)-1; pal[i]!='\0' && j>=0;`

Comment: Sorry, if it doesn't compile it's because I have made a mistake translating to English the code, because I'm Spanish. But it does compile ;-)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, thanks for that correction, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have edited the original code. Now it compiles ;-)

Comment: I think If you're successful in search of from left to right, reverse `pal` then search again.